# Display all values in columns (Query formule)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use a query function in my google sheet.
But I have a little problem :

When I have same/less "R" than date so it display me only date and not the "R"

For example:

[image]

Another example:

[image]

And now, when I have more "R" so it's display everything:

[image]

So how can I display everything when I have same or less "R" (it can b R or any letter) ?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1svXFqHVtbgMfHPZjxS3X9AKW679AqrVyMDySay2lzfw/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for your help

Comment: try something like `WHERE I IS NOT NULL OR C="R"`

Comment: it doesn't works :/

Comment: try with single quotes: `WHERE I IS NOT NULL OR C='R'`

Comment: I'm doing this: =QUERY(H1:J6;"WHERE I IS NOT NULL OR C='R'" ;0) but don't work

Comment: Oh I see I meant `J` instead of `C` `WHERE I IS NOT NULL OR J='R'`

Comment: Pls share a copy of your spreadsheet!

Comment: @trinalbadger587 same error, the "R" are not display :/

Comment: When you have a combination of string and numeric value in the same column (date is numeric), query does not work well. You then need to pass the data in the string maybe with the to_text function. To resolve your issue, please share a copy

Comment: @MikeSteelson You can look the copy

Comment: ok thanks, I will have a look at it.

Comment: access denied! plas share it

Comment: @MikeSteelson Can you try again: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1svXFqHVtbgMfHPZjxS3X9AKW679AqrVyMDySay2lzfw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=QUERY(arrayformula(to_text(H1:J6)),"WHERE Col3 IS NOT NULL " ,0)
```

the problem comes from a combination of string and numeric value in the same column (date is numeric), query does not work well and you have to convert data into strings. Because the source is now a function, you will have to use Colx instead of letter of column.

Comment: Understand, appreciate it :)